# How to use the string returned by one class in another class

Tags: java, string

What I have is a class (Rev) which is able to convert string into another string. I have tried to use the output (converted) string in another class. Making the output string public does not work on my hands. I am also not able to recall the method from Rev class. I would like to avoid exporting the output string into the file and importing it once again for another conversion, because I am sure that there is much more fancy way to do this. As you can see I am pretty new in java. Any help appreciated :) The code looks like this:

```
public class Rev {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        String s = "ACGTACCCC";
        char[] reverse = new char[s.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < reverse.length; i++) {
            switch (s.charAt(i)) {
                case 'A':
                    reverse[i] = 'T';
                    break;
                case 'T':
                    reverse[i] = 'A';
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    reverse[i] = 'G';
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    reverse[i] = 'C';
                    break;
                default: //handle error when invalid char
            }
        }
        s = new String(reverse);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

and the class (interface) where I would like to use s string is here:

```
public class InterfaceRev {
    public static void main (String []args);
        Rev revObj = new Rev();
        revObj.Rev();
    }
```

Comment: please, show the class (or the place) where you are trying to access `s`.

Comment: You need to learn about methods and return types. I'm sure your introductor Java book talks about them. The official Java tutorial also does. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html. Note an important thing that many newbies don't get: **printing** something to the screen is not the same thing as **returning** something from a method. returning is what makes it possible for another method to call the method and use the returned value.

Comment: You don't need to use 2 main methods.

Comment: I haven't actually tried it, but you might want to look into Java's `interface`s if you want anything fancier than separating your String operation into a method and calling it from the other class.

Answer (score 1):

Use methods to achieve your tasks. 
You should wrap your logic in methods giving them meaningful names.

```
public class Rev {
public String replaceCharacters(String s){
    char[] reverse = new char[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < reverse.length; i++) {
        switch (s.charAt(i)) {
            case 'A':
                reverse[i] = 'T';
                break;
            case 'T':
                reverse[i] = 'A';
                break;
            case 'C':
                reverse[i] = 'G';
                break;
            case 'G':
                reverse[i] = 'C';
                break;
            default: //handle error when invalid char
        }
    }
    String str = new String(reverse);
    return str;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "ACGTACCCC";
    Rev object = new Rev();
    String newStr = object.replaceCharacters(s);
    System.out.println(newStr); 
}
}
```

Although the task that you want to achieve can be done by using inbuilt String methods, but this is just an illustration about how you can wrap your code inside methods and access them using class' object.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! Now I can see the difference. I will keep this lesson on my mind to the end of my days :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Rev {  
    public static String convert(String str) {      
        char[] reverse = new char[str.length()];        
        for (int i = 0; i < reverse.length; i++) {
            switch (str.charAt(i)) {
                case 'A':
                    reverse[i] = 'T';
                    break;
                case 'T':
                    reverse[i] = 'A';
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    reverse[i] = 'G';
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    reverse[i] = 'C';
                    break;
                default: //handle error when invalid char
            }
        }       
        return new String(reverse);       
    }
}

public class InterfaceRev {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        System.out.println(Rev.convert("ACGTACCCC"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works fine :) Thank you for your time!